# Lazy Loading UICompositionalLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

I'm trying to **lazy load sections** in a `UICollectionView` to create a TVGuide. I'm using `UICompositionalLayout` as well as `UIDiffableDataSource` to take advantage of these new APIs plus reduce performance overhead.

I have everything working but as soon as the sections are about to reload, you see that there is a redraw issue with the `Loading...` cell. It's sized up to the first `Event` but it **should disappear seamlessly** as the events come in.

I have an image below which better shows the problem, plus **the code snippet below** which you can simply copy and paste into a blank project to test. Been trying to figure this out for weeks but just can't figure out what to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    typealias DataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, String>
    typealias DataSourceSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, String>
    
    private var dataSource: DataSource!
    private var sections: [SectionViewModel] = []
    private var cellWidths: [Int: [CGFloat]] = [:]
    
    private let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
    private let scheduleWidth: CGFloat = 1500
    
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        
        sections = (0...150).enumerated().map({ index, object in
            let event = EventCellViewModel(name: "Loading...Section-\(index)", width: scheduleWidth)
            let sectionViewModel = SectionViewModel(events: [event])
            return sectionViewModel
        })
        
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = dataSource
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionView.bounces = false
        collectionView.register(EventCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "EventCell")
        collectionView.isOpaque = true
        
        operationQueue.qualityOfService = .utility
        operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        configureDataSource()
        createDumbyData()
    }
    
    private func configureDataSource() {
        dataSource = DataSource(collectionView: collectionView, cellProvider: { [weak self] collectionView, indexPath, object in
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "EventCell", for: indexPath) as! EventCell
            let viewModel = self?.sections[indexPath.section].events[indexPath.row]
            cell.programmeTitle.text = viewModel?.name
            cell.isOpaque = true
            cell.backgroundColor = .red.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
            return cell
        })
    }
    
    private func applySnapshot() {
        operationQueue.addOperation { [weak self] in
            
            guard let self = self else { return }
            var snapshot = DataSourceSnapshot()
            
            for (sectionIndex, section) in self.sections.enumerated() {
                let sectionId = "Section-\(sectionIndex)"
                snapshot.appendSections([sectionId])
                
                let eventIds = section.events.enumerated().map { "Event-\(sectionIndex)-\($0)" }
                snapshot.appendItems(eventIds, toSection: sectionId)
            }
            
            self.dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
        }
    }
    
    private func updateSnapshot(sectionIndex: Int) {
        guard sections[sectionIndex].isLoading else { return }
        
        let newEvents = (0..<20).map {
            EventCellViewModel(name: "Event-\(sectionIndex)-\($0)")
        }
        
        if cellWidths[sectionIndex] == nil {
            cellWidths[sectionIndex] = newEvents.map { $0.width }
        }
        
        self.sections[sectionIndex].events = newEvents
        self.sections[sectionIndex].isLoading = false
        
        applySnapshot()
    }
    
    private func createDumbyData() {
        let sections = (0...150).map { index in
            SectionViewModel(events: [EventCellViewModel(name: "Loading...\(index)", width: 1500)])
        }
        
        self.sections = sections
        applySnapshot()
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment) in
            
            let items = self.layoutItems(for: sectionIndex)
            let scheduleWidth = self.scheduleWidth(for: sectionIndex)
            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(scheduleWidth),
                                                   heightDimension: .absolute(60))
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: items)
            
            // Create the section
            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .none
            section.contentInsets.bottom = 0
            return section
        }
        return layout
    }
    
    private func layoutItems(for sectionIndex: Int) -> [NSCollectionLayoutItem] {
        return cellWidths(for: sectionIndex).map { width in
            let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(width), heightDimension: .absolute(60))
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
            return item
        }
    }
    
    private func scheduleWidth(for sectionIndex: Int) -> CGFloat {
        sections[sectionIndex].events.map { $0.width }.reduce(0, +)
    }
    
    func cellWidths(for sectionIndex: Int) -> [CGFloat] {
        cellWidths[sectionIndex] ?? [1500]
    }
    
    func isLoading(for section: Int) -> Bool {
        sections[section].isLoading
    }
    
    private func numberOfEvents(for index: Int) -> Int {
        sections[index].events.count
    }
    
    private func viewModel(for sectionIndex: Int, at itemIndex: Int) -> EventCellViewModel? {
        sections[sectionIndex].events[itemIndex]
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        reloadCell(at: indexPath.section)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].events.count
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func reloadCell(at index: Int) {
        self.updateSnapshot(sectionIndex: index)
    }
}

// MARK: - ViewModels
public struct SectionViewModel: Hashable {
    var events: [EventCellViewModel]
    var isLoading = true
}

public struct EventCellViewModel {
    
    var uuid: String { return name }
    public let name: String
    public let width: CGFloat

    init(name: String, width: CGFloat = CGFloat(Int.random(in: 100...400))) {
        self.name = name
        self.width = width
    }
}

extension EventCellViewModel: Hashable {
    
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(uuid)
    }
    
    public static func ==(lhs: EventCellViewModel, rhs: EventCellViewModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.uuid == rhs.uuid
    }
}

// MARK: - Cell
class EventCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let programmeTitle = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        programmeTitle.textColor = .white
        programmeTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        contentView.addSubview(programmeTitle)
        
        contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.4).cgColor
        contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            programmeTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            programmeTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            programmeTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            programmeTitle.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configure(title: String?) {
        programmeTitle.text = title
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not *entirely* clear what you're trying to solve... Is the issue that you get a "flash" of the blue background when quickly scrolling? Are you taking the approach of showing the "Loading..." text because you expect a delay retrieving the data for the section?

Comment: Sort of. So when I quickly scroll, theres a redraw issue when the cells come in. Exactly yes, I'm using the `Loading...` text because I expect a delay from the server. Each channel will require a HTTP call to fetch its schedule (i.e. the events). Thanks for getting back

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a combination of how you're doing the layout, and "layout timing" ... but a little tough to say without being able to evaluate the code involved with making the HTTP calls.

What you *could* try...

Instead of:

```
collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear

// and

cell.backgroundColor = .red.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
```

use:

```
collectionView.backgroundColor = .red.withAlphaComponent(0.7)

// and

cell.backgroundColor = .clear
```

That *may* be sufficient... give it a try.

Perhaps worth noting: with your current approach, if you have scrolled horizontally, the "Loading..." text will not be visible - it will be "off the left side of the screen."

---

**Edit**

Try changing `animatingDifferences: false` to `true` ... see if that is acceptable.

If not, another approach could be to configure your cell to have the "Loading..." label always there, and show/hide it based on the state -- instead of changing its text and frame to the first "event."

---

**Edit 2** - *couple more thoughts...*

I think it's going to be very difficult to solve this with your current approach.

As you're seeing, a `UICollectionView` does not request the **cell** until the cell needs to be displayed.

When you have a section with a single, 1500-point width cell ("Loading..."), and you update the section with multiple, narrower cells - let's say cell 0 has a width of 200 - the collection view says:

- layout the cell frames
- if a frame is *visible*

  - request the cell content

So, since cell 0 is already visible, its frame width changes to 200 and ***then*** cell 1 is requested.

Because your cell 0 view has a border, we see the border change first.

You *could* try using a section background view and clear cells with only a "left-edge" border. Something like this:

[image]

The yellow rects show the visible part of the collection view...

- A - Section Background view
- B - Cell (gray is just to show the frame... it will be clear)
- C - Section has one Cell, in "Loading..." state. Full width.
- D - Section has multiple cells, and the frame for Cell 0 has been set
- E - No visual change, because the cell is clear and has no "right-side" border
- F - Cells have been requested
- G - UI has been updated

As a side note... Compositional Layout is really designed for multiple "disparate layout" sections. A custom `UICollectionViewLayout` may be much better suited for this type of "grid" layout.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I don't think HTTP calls are necessary for this since its mocking the exact lifecycle. I did just try your solution above, but I don't think that solves the issue, my cells require a border width so you end up seeing the `Loading...` cell with its border. See image here https://ibb.co/vmpxYFQ. FYI the code above is ready to copy and paste and use

Comment: Also, I'm aware of the horizontal issue. I'm going to have another collectionView on the left of it which will be preloaded with channels. This will then trigger the fetching on scroll

Comment: Hi @DonMag, I tried that too along with your other suggestions and I still see the same redraw issue in the image I sent previously. So I've been doing more investigation and it seems when I take out ` operationQueue.addOperation {` and add `Task(priority: .utility) {` it fixes the issue but I lose out massively on performance...I think this is the culprit

Comment: @K.Janjuha - what's happening is that the cell **frames** are being set *before* the call to `cellProvider`. So, because cell `0` is already in the hierarchy, you ***see its frame change*** while waiting for the calls to `cellProvider` on the rest of the cells in the section. Going to be tough to get around that - if even possible. That's why I suggested animating the change might be acceptable appearance. I have a *thought* on one more approach, but I'll have to get back to that later (probably not until tomorrow).

Comment: Right I see. Ok no thats cool! I'll keep playing around but I appreciate all your help on this! please take your time, thank you very much @DonMag

Comment: @K.Janjuha - see the **Edit 2** in my answer for a few more thoughts.